# Bindings inside WPF user control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In order to get into the WPF world and getting used to bindings, I've made a user control used to define a search filter. Depending on the wanted filter, the user can either enter a text, pick a date or select an item in a combo box. Here's an example with three instances of the created search control, each being of different type:

[image: Search filter example]

The good news is, everything is working but I'm not sure if everything has been done as intended.

SearchUserControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Zefix.View.UserControls.SearchUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="82" 
             d:DesignWidth="300" 
             Height="Auto"
             x:Name="SearchUserControlRoot">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Name="LabelHeaderText" Content="{Binding HeaderText, ElementName=SearchUserControlRoot}" />
            <TextBox Name="TextBoxSearchText" Text="{Binding SearchValue, ElementName=SearchUserControlRoot}" Visibility="{Binding TextBoxVisiblity, ElementName=SearchUserControlRoot}" />
            <DatePicker Name="DatePickerSearch" SelectedDate="{Binding SearchValue, ElementName=SearchUserControlRoot}" Visibility="{Binding DatePickerVisiblity, ElementName=SearchUserControlRoot}" />
            <ComboBox Name="ComboBoxSearch" Text="{Binding SearchValue, ElementName=SearchUserControlRoot}" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableValues, ElementName=SearchUserControlRoot}" Visibility="{Binding ComboBoxVisiblity, ElementName=SearchUserControlRoot}" IsEditable="True" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

SearchUserControl.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using Zefix.DataAccess;

namespace Zefix.View.UserControls {
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for SearchUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SearchUserControl {

        #region Public Dependency Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// The search value property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SearchValue", typeof (object), typeof (SearchUserControl));

        /// <summary>
        /// The available values property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AvailableValuesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("AvailableValues", typeof (IEnumerable<object>), typeof (SearchUserControl));

        /// <summary>
        /// The search type property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SearchType", typeof (SearchType), typeof (SearchUserControl));

        /// <summary>
        /// The header text property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderText", typeof (string), typeof (SearchUserControl));

        #endregion

        #region Private Dependency Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// The combo box visiblity property
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly DependencyProperty ComboBoxVisiblityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxVisiblity", typeof (Visibility), typeof (SearchUserControl));

        /// <summary>
        /// The text box visiblity property
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxVisiblityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxVisiblity", typeof (Visibility), typeof (SearchUserControl));

        /// <summary>
        /// The date picker visiblity property
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly DependencyProperty DatePickerVisiblityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DatePickerVisiblity", typeof (Visibility), typeof (SearchUserControl));

        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets or sets the type of the search.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        ///     The type of the search.
        /// </value>
        public SearchType SearchType {
            get { return (SearchType) GetValue(SearchTypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SearchTypeProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets or sets the header text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        ///     The header text.
        /// </value>
        public string HeaderText {
            get { return (string) GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the available values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The available values.
        /// </value>
        public IEnumerable<object> AvailableValues {
            get { return (IEnumerable<object>) GetValue(AvailableValuesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AvailableValuesProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the search value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The search value.
        /// </value>
        public object SearchValue {
            get { return GetValue(SearchValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SearchValueProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the combo box visiblity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The combo box visiblity.
        /// </value>
        private Visibility ComboBoxVisiblity {
            get { return (Visibility) GetValue(ComboBoxVisiblityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ComboBoxVisiblityProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the date picker visiblity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The date picker visiblity.
        /// </value>
        private Visibility DatePickerVisiblity {
            get { return (Visibility) GetValue(DatePickerVisiblityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DatePickerVisiblityProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the text box visiblity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The text box visiblity.
        /// </value>
        private Visibility TextBoxVisiblity {
            get { return (Visibility) GetValue(TextBoxVisiblityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextBoxVisiblityProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SearchUserControl" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        public SearchUserControl() {
            InitializeComponent();

            DependencyPropertyDescriptor pd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(SearchTypeProperty, typeof (SearchUserControl));
            pd.AddValueChanged(this, OnSearchTypePropertyChanged);

            // Initialize default parameters
            SearchType = SearchType.Unknown;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the search type property has changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void OnSearchTypePropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            // Hide all editors
            DatePickerVisiblity = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ComboBoxVisiblity = Visibility.Collapsed;
            TextBoxVisiblity = Visibility.Collapsed;

            // Make the correct editor visible
            switch (SearchType) {
                case SearchType.Date:
                    DatePickerVisiblity = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
                case SearchType.TextSelection:
                    ComboBoxVisiblity = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
                case SearchType.Text:
                    TextBoxVisiblity = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Instantiation of the search controls from the parent control:

```
        <ribbon:Tab Label="Search">
            <ribbon:Group Padding="0,5,0,5">
                <customcontrols:SearchUserControl x:Name="SearchUserControlCompanyName" HeaderText="company name" Margin="5,0,0,0" SearchType="Text" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
                <customcontrols:SearchUserControl x:Name="SearchUserControlCompanyNationality" HeaderText="company nationality (ISO3 code)" Margin="5,0,0,0" SearchType="TextSelection" AvailableValues="{Binding Path=CompaniesViewModel.ISO3Codes}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <customcontrols:SearchUserControl x:Name="SearchUserControlDateFounded" HeaderText="date founded" Margin="5,0,0,0" SearchType="Date" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
                <ribbon:Button Context="StatusBarItem" Name="ButtonApplyFilter" Label="Search" ImageSourceSmall="/Resources/search_magnifying_glass_find.png" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="OnButtonApplyFilterClicked" Command="{Binding Path=ApplyFilterCommand}" ScreenTipHeader="Apply the search filter" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VariantSize="Large" />
            </ribbon:Group>
        </ribbon:Tab>
```

In the SearchControl I wanted to display the correct component (textbox, datepicker or combobox) according to the set SearchType. For this the, xxxVisibility dependency properties and properties have been created (they are being set when the SearchTypeProperty notifies a property changed event). As there is no reason to expose them as public (they are being used only inside the SearchControl), I've made them private; MSDN states that bound properties MUST be public though. The project compiles and runs without an issue, but errors are being shown for the bound xxxVisibility properties with the message 'Public member expected' (can't tell if it's visual studio or resharper telling me that).

Is my approach to create this user control correct in respect to the WPF concepts?
Should the xxxVisibility properties be public (event though I don't want to expose them)?

Comment: How about having them as plain `CLR` properties and implementing `INPC` on your class?

Comment: This would probably do the trick. Conceptually I've still got an issue, as the public events raised through INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged are intended to be used inside the user control but are of no use to the outside world.

Comment: Bound properties have to be public. Binding will fail silently which you can verify in VS Output window.

Comment: After having read quite a bit about WPF, that's what I thought as well. Implementing this user control tells me otherwise. As the print screen shows, the components visibility state is being bound correctly to the private properties. I don't see anything unexpected in the VS output, what do you expect to see?

Comment: Oh i see. If i create private CLR properties, i see error in output window that blah-blah property could not be found so i have to make it public. But it works differently for DP properties, private DP's are visible to XAML. So, having private CLR property definitely not an option here.

Comment: So, my vote is to have private DP's. I see no issue in having them. :)

Comment: After having found the check box to disable resharper, the error messages 'Public member expected' in the xaml code disappeared. What confused me seems to be a resharper 'bug'. As it seems, if binding to CLR properties, they have to be public, binding to private dependency properties works though. Thanks for helping to investigate this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very difficult question to 'answer', rather than just 'comment' on. In my personal opinion, your `UserControl` has been written well and as far as I can see doesn't break any rules. Although I don't see any problem with declaring a `private` `DependencyProperty`, it *is* unusual. In this situation, developers often chose to implement a `public` `Read Only DependencyProperty` with a `private` `DependencyPropertyKey` instead:

```
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ComboBoxVisiblityPropertyKey
    = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ComboBoxVisiblity", typeof(int), 
    typeof(SearchUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed));

public static readonly DependencyProperty ComboBoxVisiblityProperty
    = ComboBoxVisiblityPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

public int ComboBoxVisiblity
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(ComboBoxVisiblityProperty); }
    protected set { SetValue(ComboBoxVisiblityPropertyKey, value); }
}
```

Some developers *may* also think it unusual that you are creating properties of type `Visibility` rather than binding `bool` values with `BoolToVisibilityConverter`s, but again... that is your prerogative. Overall, well done! :)

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry for the 'vague' question, I wanted to check if I did something fundamentally wrong somewhere. I've chosen to expose the Visibility property to avoid the additional bool->visibility converter :)